# Connector 2-pin identification

Tags: identification, connector

What is this type of connector?

Pins: 2
Pitch: 4 mm (0.158 inch)

[image: Male Top]
[image: Male Hole]
[image: Female Top]

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a knock off of the [JST SL](https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/index.php?series=237).

I used my Identicon utility to identify it: [https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=latched_w2w_conn&fl=0000000010000000000000000000000000-500-|4|2|||](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=latched_w2w_conn&fl=0000000010000000000000000000000000-500-%7C4%7C2%7C%7C%7C)

Comment: The utility is great, bookmarking.

Both housings - plug & receptable looks the same as of JST SL,
but pin and socket are different - vertical vs. horizontal.